# Can Unity based on Compiz already be fully used?

Tags: 10.10, unity, compiz, ati

Last, time several month ago, I installed Unity to test it in maverick. I had the problem that it didn't work as expected.

Instead of Unity I only got a white screen, I'm not 100% sure what the problem was, but it should have to do with my Radeon Xpress graphics card I think.

Is there another method of getting Unity to work together with this graphics card in Maverick?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unity Compiz is only available if you are using Ubuntu 11.04, which is still in early development.

At one point the Ubuntu developers were planning on backporting Unity Compiz to 10.10, but they later [decided against it](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2010-November/032078.html):

> Hi everybody,
>
> As some of you may know, there have been some discussions about
>   backporting
>   "unity compiz" to maverick as we had backported unity to lucid with a
>   dedicated ppa and its own session.
>
> However, after some porting discussions and following the natty work I
>   think
>   we should perhaps consider not doing that because it's going to take
>   quite
>   some work for a moderated benefit and we would better spend those
>   efforts in
>   making natty rocking.

Answer (score 2):

Unity in Natty (based on Compiz) works quite well on my r700 and Cedar (HD 4xxx and HD 5xxx cards), with the exception of some crash bugs that are getting fixed.  As far as I'm aware, the older r300-r500 cards work better, so your problem probably doesn't exist in Natty.

Of course, that requires running Natty, which at this stage (between Alpha 1 and 2) is not necessarily a good idea for any machine you need to work!

Why not try a LiveCD - you'll be able to test Unity with minimal risk to your system.

Comment: very good point. i'll give it a try. hope that i won't like unity to much, or i'll have a problem because of not being able to use it in maverick :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand your question, but the new compiz-based unity is not available for Maverick. For now, stick with the old GNOME Desktop.

Comment: ah,ok. i had the hope, that someone perhaps can tell me more to the bug that unity just gives a white screen instead of rendering its gui. so perhaps since the compiz based unity isn't yet available i could tweak the old unity to work.

Comment: the old bug in unity is rather hard to fix.