# Is there a way to install the latest version of Unity in 10.10?

Tags: 10.10, unity, ppa, backport

Is there a PPA or hack I can use to install the latest version of Unity in 10.10? I want to use Unity as it is in 11.04, but I don't want to run alpha versions of everything else.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Unity based on Compiz already be fully used?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16789/can-unity-based-on-compiz-already-be-fully-used)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A while back I maintained a jhbuild moduleset for Unity allowing you to run a full Unity session installed in a sandbox.  You can find it on https://launchpad.net/unity-jhbuild - but I can guarantee that it doesn't work in its current state - it *will* require you to fiddle with the unity.modules file and maybe employ a bit of dark magic - but it definitely can be made to work.

This of course all means you have to do a lot of compilation, which may not be what you are after. JHBuild eases the pain a little, but it's not as easy as a set of .debs :-)

Answer (score 5):

No there isn't.
Firstly they were planning to backport but they decided not to backport.

> As some of you may know, there have been some discussions about
>   backporting
>   "unity compiz" to maverick as we had backported unity to lucid with a
>   dedicated ppa and its own session.
>
> However, after some porting discussions and following the natty work I
>   think
>   we should perhaps consider not doing that because it's going to take
>   quite
>   some work for a moderated benefit and we would better spend those
>   efforts in
>   making natty rocking.

Here is the [relevant discussion](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2010-November/032078.html).

Answer (score 0):

Hey, but you say you want to use Unity without going for unstable stuff. But Unity **itself** is still **unstable**, so there is no way for *safe* testing Unity. Just be patient (or courageous and upgrade to natty).